# useSWR Not Including Cookies

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-hooks, next.js, vercel

useSWR is not including the cookie for a given domain, while a fetch, placed in the useEffect of a component, does. The fetch request is exactly the same as the fetcher passed to useSWR. Both include the credentials: "include" option.

The fetcher and useEffect that includes the simple fetch are included below:

Fetcher:

```
export function fetcher(url) {
    fetch(url, {
        credentials: "include"
    })
    .then((res) =\> res.json())
}
```

useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url,{
    credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json()
    .then(data => console.log(data)))
}, [])
```

Both requests return the data correctly (as the endpoint does not yet require the cookie), the two requests look identical in dev tools, with the exception of the fetch in the useEffect including the cookie header and the fetch made by useSWR not including the cookie header.

What do I need to configure differently so that useSWR requests include the relevant cookies?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Could you provide a [mre]?